# ¿Cómo puedo validar que varios editText no estén vacíos?

Tags: android, bucle-for, kotlin, edittext

Tengo varios `EditText` dentro de un `ConstraintLayout` y quiero validar que no estén vacíos. Si bien puedo validarlos 1x1, quiero hacer una función que asi tu tengas 20 editTexts los recorra con un `for` y te responda `"Complete todos los Campos"` o `"Todos Completos"`, según corresponda.

Este es el código que llevo hasta ahora. Valida pero entra en un bucle infinito con el Toast.

```
binding.buttonLogin.setOnClickListener {
    val contador = binding.constraintLayoutLogin.childCount
    for (i in 1..contador) {
        val variable = binding.constraintLayoutLogin.getChildAt(i)
        if (variable == null) {
            continue
        } Toast.makeText (this, "Complete todos los Campos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        else(Toast.makeText(this, "Todos Completos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show())
    }
}
```

`constraintLayoutLogin` es el ID del constraint que contiene los editTexts

Comment: Podrías explicar mejor lo que intentas lograr? El código que muestras no está haciendo ninguna validación sobre los campos y ni siquiera podría compilar porque hay una línea suelta entre el `if` y el `else`

Comment: Quiero validar los editText, si bien puedo llamar 1x1, quiero hacer un codigo que asi tu tengas 20 edit text para validarlos que no estén nulos, con el for los recorra y te responda "Tienes campos vacios"., si todos los campos estan llenos, puedas avanzar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que tienes el código para mostrar el toast dentro del `for`. Esto hace que se muestre un nuevo toast por cada campo que validas. Además la validación que haces no es correcta

```
val variable = binding.constraintLayoutLogin.getChildAt(i)
if (variable == null) { ... }
```

Ese código lo único que hace es checkear que la view exista. Nunca validaste su contenido. El texto ingresado en el editText se encuentra en la propiedad `text` pero para acceder a ella necesitas hacer un cast porque el método `getChildAt()` retorna un objeto `View` que no tiene esta propiedad.

Puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera

```
binding.buttonLogin.setOnClickListener {
    var todoCompleto = true
    for (i in 0 until binding.constraintLayout.childCount) {
        val editText = binding.constraintLayout.getChildAt(i) as EditText
        if (editText.text.isBlank()) {
            todoCompleto = false
            break
        }
    }
    val mensaje = if (todoCompleto) "Todos Completos" else "Complete todos los Campos"
    Toast.makeText(this, mensaje, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
```

Sólo asegurate que todos los elementos del constraintLayout sean editTexts porque de lo contrario el cast fallará.